# store value (ID) for dynamically created dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got an issue storing values in dynamically created buttons whitch are able to open dialog.
 Dialog is same for all buttons so I have a definition like this:

```
$('<div id="dialog-form" title="Change coordinates">' +
      '<p class="validateTips">Both fields are required.</p>' +
      '<form>' +
       '<fieldset>' +
        '<label for="lon">Longitude (decimal)</label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="lon" id="lon" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">' +
        '<label for="lat">Latitude (decimal)</label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">' +
        '<input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">' +
      '</fieldset>' +
    '</form>' +
    '</div>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Then I'm generating dialog buttons with special "create" button:

```
$( "#create" ).button().on( "click", function()
    {
            var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            btn1.id = "change_coord";
            var t1 = document.createTextNode("Change coordinates");
            btn1.appendChild(t1);
            document.body.appendChild(btn1);
            generator++;
    });
```

Then I have a dialog declaration and functions to work with my dialog inputs and after this, I'm trying to print inputs and my id ( value from generator ). Inputs are cool but id doesn't work.
For example I generate 3 buttons like btn1:1, btn2:2, btn3:3 (button:id), but id output for all buttons is 3.
My app will create dynamically objects and I want to modify this objects by this dialog. And "ID" value will be used as a "pointer" to my DB. So when I click first created button, doesn't matter how many buttons I've created, it still has to have a "ID" value == 1
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/7rr85xuw/1/) to simulate my situation.
Thank you all for your time and opinions.

Comment: Seems overly complex but not really sure what exactly you are trying to do with creating multiple dialogs that are all the same. Why not use one dialog?

Comment: @charlietfl because my app will create dynamically objects and I want to modify this objects by this dialog. And "ID" value will be used as a "pointer" to my DB. So when I click first created button, doesn't matter how many buttons I've created, it still has to have a "ID" value == 1

Answer (score 0):

IDs are meant to be unique, yet your function is spawning cloned buttons with the same IDs.

```
btn1.id = "change_coord";
```

Either do something to make them unique, or use classes.

---

Issue #2

You're using a var `generator` to generate IDs (no longer talking about the HTML IDs, as above). Then you try to access the generator value when you call `addUser`, expecting you'll get the `generator` value from the time the dialog was created. It doesn't work that way, you'd always get the **current** value of `generator`. In order to fix it, you need to increment the generator inside the `addUser` function, not when you create those dialog-popping buttons. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/7rr85xuw/2/

Comment: IDs are definitely an issue here, but I'm not sure if there are more problems. Do you mind showing in your question how you're reading the IDs?

Comment: Maybe there is a little misunderstanding in ID, I mean ID like to assign a special value to my button. This ID will be used as a "pointer" to my DB, where I want to store dialog inputs. And in application I'll dynamically generate objects and every object will have this button with unique "pointer".

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood. I just updated my answer with the working fiddle. However, please also fix the HTML ID issue I mentioned first because it's a proper practice and it might get you in trouble when you least expect it.

Comment: I'm really sorry but still, when I generate 2 btns, and use them like: btn1, btn2 and btn1 it will output numbers: 1, 2, 3. But my goal is to output: 1, 2, 1. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: or add the generator value to data attributes

Comment: Using data attributes is the way to go then.

Comment: @Shomz You mean to do it like this: btn1.data( id ); ? But how can I read the value of the clicked button in my addUser() function?

Comment: @charlietfl You mean to do it like this: btn1.data( id ); ? But how can I read the value of the clicked button in my addUser() function?